# Speed up ORDER BY when ordering by temporary variable?

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering how I might speed this query up with indices or something else if it's at all possible. I don't know if it's possible with my current query.

The query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  metric,
  out_metric,
  run_every,
  last_downsampled_window,
  query,
  (last_updated + run_every)::bigint - $1 AS time_until_update
FROM downsamplers
WHERE worker_id = $2
ORDER BY time_until_update ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Where `$1` is the current unix timestamp in nanos. And `$2` is just an id.

And the table schema looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE downsamplers (
  id serial,
  metric text,
  out_metric text,
  run_every bigint,
  last_downsampled_window bigint,
  last_updated bigint NOT NULL,
  worker_id int,
  query jsonb
)
```

Basically I'm using this query to get the item from downsamplers with the earliest time_until_update.

Comment: Creating index on   worker_id  would help if table contains lots of data.

Comment: Noted, thanks. I was hoping to optimize the `time_until_update` aspect though.

Comment: That's not a "temporary variable" - it's a _column alias_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create a generated column on last_updated + run_every.  You could then create an index on this generated column.  Finally within your query, do the order by only on the generated column.  The order by on the generated column will be exactly the same as the order by - $1 as $1 is effectively a constant, and therefore affects all values by the same amount, thus having no impact on the order at all.